# Trouble with function not being called from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a short game for class that has already been graded. I cannot get the winOrLose() function to execute given parameters from the on.click event (JQuery). I'm new to programming and really want to understand what I'm doing wrong that is keeping this from working. Any help would be appreciated.

I don't receive an error. Once the condition of a win or loss is met (exceeding or meeting the assigned randomNum), the function does not execute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



  // ================Variables ============================

  var randomNum = 0;
  var totalScore = 0;
  var wins = 0;
  var losses = 0;
  var button1 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button2 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button3 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button4 = getRandomInt(1, 12);

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  // ================ Functions =========================



  // Get Random Number and Assign to random-number-target
  randomNum = $("#random-number-target").text(getRandomInt(19, 120));


  function winOrLose() {
    if (totalScore > randomNum) {
      console.log("you lose!");
      losses++;
      $("#losses-target").text(losses);
      // totalScore = 0;
      resetGame();
    } else if (totalScore === randomNum) {
      // end game if Total Score == Random (You Win message) and update wins div
      console.log("you win!");
      wins++;
      $("#wins-target").text(wins);
      // totalScore = 0;
      resetGame();
    };
  };

  function resetGame() {
    randomNum = $("#random-number-target").text(getRandomInt(19, 120));
    totalScore = 0;
    button1 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button2 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button3 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button4 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  };


  // Button #1 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
  function startGame() {

    $("#img01").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button1;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #2 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img02").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button2;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #3 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img03").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button3;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #4 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img04").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button4;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });
  };

  $(document).on("click", startGame());

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1><img src="assets/images/crystalHead.jpg" id="imgHead" alt="Crystal Collector"></h1>
</div>

<div class="instructions">
  <p>You will be given a random number at the start of the game </p>
  <p>There are four crystal pictures shown and each contains a hidden value</p>
  <p>You win the game by matching the given number exactly</p>
  <p></p>

</div>

<div>Number to Match:</div>
<div id="random-number-target"> </div>

<div id="scoreboard">
  <br> Wins:
  <p id="wins-target"></p>
  Losses:
  <p id="losses-target"></p>
</div>



<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal01.jpg" id="img01" onclick=></div>
<!-- <input type="image"  id="img01" src="assets/images/crystal01.jpg" alt="click"> -->
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal02.jpg" id="img02"></div>
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal03.jpg" id="img03"></div>
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal04.jpg" id="img04"></div>

<div>Total Score: </p>
</div>
<div class="total-score-title"></div>

<div class="total-score"><span id="totalScoreTarget"> </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well? Also, can you tell us what error you are receiving when you try to call the function?

Comment: Possibly because `$(document).on("click", startGame());` is restarting the game on every click.

Comment: Andy, I tried wrapping the game in a function and calling the function at the end of my code, but that wasn't working either. I just tried commenting out the $(document).on("click", startGame()); and it stops working altogether. It doesn't reset the randomNum so I don't think the whole game is restarting, but will keep on experimenting around this.

Comment: @AndyG that seems to be the problem. @Richard if you want to start the game when the dom is ready, it makes sense to just call the `startGame()` function without the `document.on("click",...)` part. Or if you want, you can always keep a start button and start the game after you click that. :-)

Comment: @Lloyd and AndyG thank you. I just tried the startGame() function standalone and the winOrLose() function still isn't executing. I'm still digging into this and appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `winOrLose()` is being called, just add a `console.log` right at the beginning and you'll see it...

Your problem lies in the `randomNum` variable, you are assigning a jQuery object to it instead of an integer... assigning the return of the `getRandomInt()` function to it, then set it in the `text()` of `#random-number-target`. If you do it in just one line, the variable will be holding the element, not the number, so `totalScore > randomNum` or `totalScore === randomNum` will never evaluate to true.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ================Variables ============================

  var randomNum = 0;
  var totalScore = 0;
  var wins = 0;
  var losses = 0;
  var button1 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button2 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button3 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  var button4 = getRandomInt(1, 12);

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  // ================ Functions =========================

  // Get Random Number and Assign to random-number-target
  randomNum = getRandomInt(19, 120)
  $("#random-number-target").text(randomNum);


  function winOrLose() {
    console.clear()
    console.log("winOrLose Called", totalScore, randomNum)
    if (totalScore > randomNum) {
      console.log("you lose!");
      losses++;
      $("#losses-target").text(losses);
      // totalScore = 0;
      resetGame();
    } else if (totalScore === randomNum) {
      // end game if Total Score == Random (You Win message) and update wins div
      console.log("you win!");
      wins++;
      $("#wins-target").text(wins);
      // totalScore = 0;
      resetGame();
    };
  };

  function resetGame() {
    randomNum = $("#random-number-target").text(getRandomInt(19, 120));
    totalScore = 0;
    button1 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button2 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button3 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
    button4 = getRandomInt(1, 12);
  };


  // Button #1 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
  function startGame() {

    $("#img01").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button1;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #2 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img02").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button2;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #3 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img03").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button3;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });

    // Button #4 Click id="img01" - add value of random number to id totalScoreTarget
    $("#img04").on("click", function() {
      totalScore += button4;
      $("#totalScoreTarget").text(totalScore);
      winOrLose();
    });
  };

  startGame();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1><img src="assets/images/crystalHead.jpg" id="imgHead" alt="Crystal Collector"></h1>
</div>

<div>Number to Match:</div>
<div id="random-number-target"> </div>

<div id="scoreboard">
  <br> Wins:
  <p id="wins-target"></p>
  Losses:
  <p id="losses-target"></p>
</div>

<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal01.jpg" id="img01" onclick=></div>
<!-- <input type="image"  id="img01" src="assets/images/crystal01.jpg" alt="click"> -->
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal02.jpg" id="img02"></div>
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal03.jpg" id="img03"></div>
<div class="crystal-pics" id="pic1" value=0><img src="assets/images/crystal04.jpg" id="img04"></div>

<div>Total Score:</div>
<div class="total-score-title"></div>
<div class="total-score">
  <span id="totalScoreTarget"> </span>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: damn, you've been faster - i started with exactly the same line in my answer ;)